# How can I set an Overlay on top when I click on it

Tags: z-index, openlayers

I have an Openlayers map with a lot of overlays (Point-coordinates).
These overlays are often very close to each other or **overlapping**.

When I click on an existing Overlay I want the Overlay to be **set on top**, so that it is **fully seen**, not behind any other Overlay.

So far I have only seen that the **Layers** can be set with an z-index. Is it possible to do that with overlays, too?

I would like to do something like that:

```
map.setLayerIndex(markers, 99);
```

but with an overlay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overlays are controls, which are positioned on an coordinate instead of being in a fixed place. They are basically nothing more but regular html `div` elements and change position with the map.

This also means, you can apply normal CSS styling and use `z-index` on them.

```js
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [layer],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

// Vienna marker
var marker1 = new ol.Overlay({
  position: ol.proj.fromLonLat([16.3725, 48.208889]),
  positioning: 'center-center',
  element: document.getElementById('marker1'),
  stopEvent: false,
  className: 'm1 ol ol-overlay-container ol-selectable'
});
map.addOverlay(marker1);

marker2 = new ol.Overlay({
  position: ol.proj.fromLonLat([23.3725, 48.208889]),
  positioning: 'center-center',
  element: document.getElementById('marker2'),
  stopEvent: false,
  className: 'm2 ol ol-overlay-container ol-selectable'
});
map.addOverlay(marker2);



function clicked(selector) {
  console.log('clicked overlay', selector);
  document.querySelectorAll(".ol").forEach(function(el){ 
    el.classList.remove('active');
  });
  document.querySelector(selector).classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
html, body, .map {
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.marker {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #088;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #0FF;
}

.m1 .marker {
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.active {
  z-index: 1234782904789;
}
.active .marker {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.0.0/legacy/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.0.0/legacy/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="marker1" title="Marker" class="marker" onclick="clicked('.m1')"></div>
<div id="marker2" title="Marker" class="marker" onclick="clicked('.m2')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer works, but it doesn't preserve the z-order of the overlays, it only guarantees that the clicked one will be on top. Since it is the only element with a z-index in this stacking context, the z-order of the other elements will be random.

Here is a solution that brings the clicked overlay to the front, while preserving the current z-order of all the other ones:

```
export function bringToFront (map: PluggableMap, clickedOverlayElement: HTMLElement) {
  const overlays = map.getOverlays().sort(zIndexComparator);

  overlays.forEach((overlay, i) => {
    const element = overlay.get('element');
    const container = pointInfo.closest('.ol-overlay-container') as HTMLElement;
    container.style.zIndex = element === clickedOverlayElement ? overlays.length.toFixed() : i.toFixed();
  });
}

function getOverlayContainer (overlay: Overlay) {
  return overlay.get('element').closest('.ol-overlay-container') as HTMLElement;
}

function zIndexComparator (a: Overlay, b: Overlay) {
  return (getOverlayContainer(a).style.zIndex > getOverlayContainer(b).style.zIndex)
    ? 1
    : -1;
}
```

Just call the `bringToFront()` function when your overlay element is clicked.